# How to use spring restTemplate.exchange directly with json

Tags: java, spring, rest

I use springs restTemplate for sending requests to a rest server. To make things a little bit more complicated I want to send a String which already is a json string directly via restTemplate to the server. Unfortunatly I get http return code 400 (Bad Request)

My code looks similar to

```
String request = "{\"some\":\"value\"};
RequestEntity<String> request1  = new RequestEntity<String>(request, httpHeaders, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(endpoint));
restTemplate.exchange(request1, String.class);
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a special header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the API expects in `request` and what it returns in the `response`. If it accepts and returns `json` then you need to convert the request string into json object, once done, you can probably use `postForEntity` method of `RestTemplate` to return the value, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String request = "{\"some\":\"value\"}";
Map<String, String> dataMap = objectMapper.readValue(request, Map.class);
ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://someurl", dataMap, Map.class);
System.out.println("Response : " + responseEntity.getBody());
```

The above examples uses `Jackson` to serialise/deserialise the objects (repo [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)), you can use any `json` framework to do so.

Comment: Interesting. I found a similar solution but I mapped the json to its pojo and it also worked. Your solution is cool because it is independend of a pojo. Do you know why I have to do your trick? Because it makes my string a real json?

Comment: I'd probably recommend using pojo as well. The only reason I used `Map` is because I didn't have much knowledge about your object structure, Pojo gives us more control.

Comment: In general I agree witth you. This time I need a asynchronous behavior and do not know when I have to send my rest call. At the time I have to do it the pojo might have been changed. Thanks again for your help.